# How do I routes between pages, ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a list of products in my application.

My products have an **id** number.

And I want to get to the details of my products with these **ID numbers**

**View:**

```
<div ng-init="urunGetir()" >  
  <ion-item ng-repeat="urun in urunler" class="item-thumbnail-left positive" id="anasayfa-list-item5" ng-href="/urundetay{{ urun.urun_id }}" target="_self" ng-value="urun_id=urun.urun_id" ng-click="urunDetay(urun_id)">
    <img ng-src="http://www.elli2.com/img_gorsel_/urunler/{{  data[urun.urun_id]  }}" ng-init="gorsel(urun.urun_id)">
    <h2positive>{{ urun.urun_adi }} 
      <p style="white-space:normal; font-weight: bold;">Fiyat: <span ng-show="urun.urun_ana_fiyat!=0">{{  urun.urun_ana_fiyat }} ₺</span><span ng-show="urun.urun_indirim_yuzde != 0">{{ urun.urun_fiyati }}</span></p>
      <ion-option-button class="button-positive" ></ion-option-button>
    </h2positive>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

**Route:**

```
.state('urundetay',{ url:"/urundetay/:urun_id", templateUrl:'templates/urunDetay.html', controller:'urunDetayCtrl' })
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('urunDetayCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams','$http','$rootScope','$routeParams', 
function($scope,$stateParams,$http,$rootScope,$routeParams){ }])
```

I'm new at ionic, I'm waiting for your help

Answer (score 0):

it will be simple in this scenerio :

> step 1 : bind function to your html

```
  <ion-item ng-repeat="urun in urunler" ng-click="urunDetay(urun.id)">
```

> Step 2 : now in controller your function envoke when ever this item is
>   clicked

```
$scope.urunDetay = function(urunId){
$state.go('detail',{id : urunId})
//here you gets the id , now you can pass this id to the route
(your detail template url should be 'detail/:id')
}
```

> Step 3 : template render against the url **detail/:id**, now you can get
>   the **urun.id** in this controller by

```
$state.params.id
```

request the API by this id to gets the detail of the item

Comment: Work it, Thank you

Comment: @CanKurucu welcome, kindly approve my answer if it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

If you are new to Ionic, I suggest use Ionic latest version 3.3.0 with Angular 4. In ionic you do not need angular router for routing between the pages. Simply use Ionic NavController and NavParams to navigate and pass data from pages. You can read more on navigation on Ionic documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/). If you are new to Angular 2 world take a look at quick start sample [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html)